# msbuild fails creating COM wrapper for "Windows Script Host Object Model"

Tags: visual-studio-2015, com, com-interop, wsh

### The situation

- I just reinstalled windows 10 and my dev tools, while keeping my data
- I am using VS2015 update 3.
- I have a solution with several projects.
- The solution is under version control (git) and I am the only one in my team experiencing this issue.

### The problem

Build and Rebuild fail. 
In the output I can see that the build of the root project (the one all others depend on directly or indirectly) fails with the following error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2399,5): warning MSB3290: Failed to create the wrapper assembly for type library "IWshRuntimeLibrary". Access denied (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
```

**IWshRuntimeLibrary** is part of the "**Windows Script Host Object Model**" type library. It resides in the **wshom.ocx** which can be found in *%SYSTEMROOT%\System32* respectivley *%SYSTEMROOT%\syswow64*.

The reference to IWshRuntimeLibrary is marked with the yellow exclamation mark symbol in visual studio.

### What did not work

- I re-added the reference but that did not help.
- I cloned the source code into a different location

### What worked

- I started visual studio as an administrator. There where no problems building the solution. Unfortunately this is not an option for daily use but emphasizes that this is a access rights problem

Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: Why did you reinstall Windows??  It did not seem to get better.

Comment: @HansPassant: Just to be clear. I did not (!) have the problem before I reinstalled. I reinstalled windows because I was not able to boot it anymore and all attempts to repair it, failed. Edit: And that might have been caused by a) uninstalling the Hololens Emulator or b) cleaning up drive c a little to good ;-)

Comment: Hi, I have the same warning (Failed to create the wrapper assembly for type library ...). Have you resolved it?

Comment: @Mergasov Unfortunately not. I knew I was going to get new hardware and abandon the machine a few weeks later so I used VS as admin until then.

Answer (score 1):

Readding not the reference, but COM "Windows Script Host Object Model" was helpful for me.[image]

Comment: I have the exact same issue but it started after I reinstalled Windows due to a system crash. After reinstalling, Visual Studio 2017 gave me the same E_ACCESSDENIED while trying access the COM objects during a build, however it'll worked just fine if I started VS2017 as an Admin. I didn't understand your solution here, I tried to remove and add the COM Type Library reference again but it still it can't access it in normal (non administrative) mode.